Argo curl POST request to Azure pipeline for automation QA test start
I am using Argo curl POST sync request to trigger QA pipeline, which is testing whole application, but now we want to change to pipeline test just service which had build trigger.
But at this point, with our use case, we don't know which build triggered pipeline, as pipeline is only one and run tests for whole application. Idea is to send with POST request some varible/value, for example, testServiceName, and in Maven, QA engineers will configure, if is variable testServiceName, value = users, run tests for users service, if is home, run tests for home service etc..
I hope I explane in good way, below is our code which is used for curl POST sync
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
 generateName: qagreen-test-
 annotations:
   argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "2"
   argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
   argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: HookSucceeded
spec:
 template:
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: qagreen-test
       image: alpine/curl
       command: [curl]
       args: ["-X", "POST", "--location", "https://dev.azure.com/our_org/our_project/_apis/pipelines/xxxx/runs?api-version=7.0", "--header", "Content-Type: application/json", "--header", "Authorization: Basic YnRmN2ZlQGJvc2NoLmTOKEN29qZ2ltdWJqNmRza2U3Mm5za3U0dmFx", "--data", "{'resources': {'repositories': { 'self': { 'refName': 'refs/heads/master'} } } }"]
       resources: # limit the resources
         limits:
           memory: 32Mi
           cpu: 100m
     restartPolicy: Never
 backoffLimit: 0

